# Microservice architecture - is database shared across all instances of the service?

Tags: microservices

I understand that microservice architecture suggests that each service should have its own private database. But when such a service is scaled, then is it one db per service instance or one db shared by all service instances?

Comment: This is a good question. I'd recommend against trying to horizontally scale stateful services if the data is interdependent among services. If horizontally scaling means being able to partition the data such that no two services will have to compete for the same data, then you can do it.

Answer (score 2):

Your first statement may be misleading to some: "each service should have its own private database."

Your architecture should be careful about sharing a single set of tables across multiple services-- that sharing frequently leads to a shared schema dependency, which creates a tight coupling that makes it difficult to update the schema without updating many of the services that share that schema at the same time.

However, sharing a single database instance (or database cluster) doesn't mean your services are accessing the same tables or even the same schema within the database.  And if they aren't accessing the same tables, they aren't coupled.  (Relying on the same database instance isn't coupling any more than relying on the same network.  Don't confuse coupling with shared infrastructure.)

Frequently, multiple instances of the same service share the same database.  In my opinion, there is nothing inherently wrong with this, but there are some things to be aware of.  If you go this route, you need to be very careful when making changes to the data schema.  Because multiple versions of that service may be accessing the data at the same time during updates, any schema changes need to compatible to at least any two adjacent versions.  If you add a column or table, that's fine.  The older version won't attempt to use it, so there will be no problem.  (Note too, that the older version won't populate it either.)  Removing a column or table is another problem entirely and to make that kind of breaking change, you will likely need to do it in several smaller steps to ensure that the older version of the service isn't broken.  It can be done, it's just tougher.

Answer (score 2):

*A general rule of microservice development is that each microservice
should manage its own data. In an ideal world, the data managed by
each service would be completely independent. There would be no need
to propagate data changes made in one service to other services.
In the real world, however, complete data independence is impossible.
There will always be overlaps between the data used in different
services, Consequently, as an architect, you need to think carefully about
sharing data and managing data consistency. You need to think about
the microservices as an interacting system rather than as individual
units.*

> This means:

1. You should isolate data within each system service with as little
   data sharing as possible.
2. If data sharing is mavoidable, you should design microservices so
   that most sharing is read-only, with a minimal number of
   services responsible for data updates.
3. If services are replicated in your system, you must include a
   mechanism that can keep the database copies used by replica
   services consistent.

Answer (score 1):

Good question indeed. I would answer it like: "at least a database per microservice (not instance)"

A concern is the scalability of the databse itself, i.e. can service instances outscale the database?

If so, you could opt for e.g. an in-memory database or a sidecar for your microservice. The database would be ephemeral and you would need to populate it after the pod/container (re)starts. So the state not really lives in the database.
Apache Kafka is a tool that fits this spot, as it would allow you to populate the database after the service comes up and also provides the tooling to synchronize state for all currently running and future instances. But successfully implementing a Event-Sourcing with Kafka is not a trivial task, but you could come the conclusion that you don't need databases at all.

So the question remains, can service instances *really* outscale the database?
The answer would be "no" more often than not.

So by having a database instance per microservice (physically or logically) already gives you a lot in terms of "loose coupling and cohesive behaviour" as you don't share databases.

Another concern are breaking changes to the database between versions of the microservice. If things go wrong you could find yourself being unable to rollback. An ephemeral database could sync itself up in a compatible way.

Some say they change database technologies throughout the lifetime of a microservice, I never had the neccessity to do so, but an in-memory/sidecar approach would fit here very well.

Comment: Can you share with me some good references of maintaining data consistency in a microservice architecture? Ofcourse I have googled, but always good to have more information

Comment: Not really, no. This is due to the fact that you are facing the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem. What results from this, greatly if not totally depends on your business and the guarantees it needs.

Comment: I have read that event sourcing, and CQRS, SAGA are preferred appraoches

Comment: None of them are about Consistency.
Event Sourcing is about recreating state to a any given point in time,
CQRS allows you to have different models for reading and writing, 
and SAGA is about distributed transactions by providing for every operation an undo-operation.

Comment: A database per instance means adding the additional storage (whether on disk or in memory) of that data in each instance and the cost of keeping that data up-to-data in each instance as well as in a canonical source from whence the service pulls data during initialization.  Those additional space and performance demands have to be weighed when deciding whether to use a shared database or independent (in pod) SBs.

Answer (score 0):

I presume you share one database with all instances of one microservice. So that one update is available for every instance of the same microservice immediately. You may use one database instance per microservice instance to avoid the database as a single point of failure. But you would have to keep in sync every database which, it seems like an unnecesary overload for the database and application. I assume the database is able to keep a group of db instances in sync (every insert,update, delete is properly propagated).